# Time aggregation in SQL

Tags: sql, time, aggregation

I have a data-set which includes time {hh,mm,ss} and temperature.
I want to aggregate the temperature with respect to the time.
For each minute in a specific hour there are number of temperature records and I want to calculate the average of them to have a single value for each minute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time         ;temperature
"01:06:46+02";19.175
"01:08:45+02";19.1456
"01:09:22+02";19.1652
"01:09:46+02";19.1652
"01:10:16+02";19.1456
"01:10:46+02";19.1456
"01:11:46+02";19.1456
"01:12:46+02";19.1358
"01:14:16+02";19.1162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date functions ( http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ ) to get more general (less precise) time [i.e. Hour and Minute only], group by that and use Average SQL function to get your average value.